# Any way to fix display errors (Ï@ etc..) when looking at hex values in SAS EG?

Tags: sas, hex, display

Are there any ways to improve readability of data stored as hex values in EG? I prefer to use EG because I find the readability/code editor more user friendly than base SAS but the display of this data as a bunch of ascii text makes it less than ideal.

Obviously I can read in the formats, but since swapping between 32/64bit format issues are an on-going pain I'd like to know I'm looking at "a1"x not "" as a bit of a stop gap measure to alleviate the burden and at least make it on par with Base SAS.

Comment: Do you have the "Use local formats where applicable" option checked in EG? If so, uncheck it. That option causes a lot of formatting issues for me. Additionally, make sure that the columns are set with the "Hex" format.

Comment: That option is unselected currently